# $L^*$ decidable $\implies$ $L$ is decidable

Tags: computer-science, decidability

I know decidable languages are closed under concatenation and union. But i am having a hard time finding an counter argument (i think its wrong).

Can you help me find the right direction to proof/disproof this lemma ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't true. Let $L$ be the language consisting of the symbols $a$ and $b$ together with an undecidable set of strings in that alphabet. In this case, $L^*$ has all strings, and so it is decidable, but $L$ is not.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Unfortunately' ?

Comment: I had just meant that it would be unfortunate, if one had been hoping to prove that it was true.  I was reacting to the title of your post, but I see that in the body of the post, you did say that you thought it was wrong. So we're on the same page.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and answering my question.

Comment: Another traditional example: Every language may be encoded over a unary alphabet (e.g., see words over $\{a, b\}$ as binary numbers, and encode a number $n$ by $a^n$).  But the star of any unary language is regular.

Comment: @MichaëlCadilhac why is the star of any unary language is regular?

Comment: @dave see http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21765/kleene-star-of-an-infinite-unary-language-always-yields-a-regular-language/21775

Comment: @dave It is not too difficult to see that $A$ is any set of words in a unary alphabet, then $A^*$ is eventually periodic, and all such languages are regular.